# Always get a Security Error for Internal HTTPS Website

Tags: networking, https, certificate, google-chrome

Full disclosure, I asked this question over at Ask Different (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96776/always-get-a-security-error-for-internal-https-website) but didn't get much helpful feedback. I'm hoping this question fits better here.

My company recently changed an internal site to use HTTPS instead of HTTP (it is our Jira site in case that matters). From what I can tell, this site is using an internal certificate. On our work computers this certificate appears to be pre installed so the website comes up without trouble in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. However, my personal computer is a Mac (OS X 10.8.4) and I am having major troubles accessing the site through any browser. I have followed instructions to install the certificate in my Keychain and I believe I have successfully done that, but I am still not able to access the site.

**When Accessing the site I Get:**

**Chrome**: **Invalid Server Certificate** You attempted to reach jira.surescripts.local, but the server presented an invalid certificate.

**Safari**: **Safari can't open the page** Safari can't open the page "https://jira.local:8081/" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "jira.local"

In Chrome when I view the certificate information it I see: Intermediate certificate authority. Expires: Thursday, May 21, 2015 1:19:28 PM Central Daylight Time. This certificate is valid

To make sure that it wasn't something strange with our company's VPN, I installed a Windows 7 virtual machine on my Mac and installed the certificate in Windows and am able to successfully log on to the site how I always would.

I am not much of an expert with certificates and I really don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is your time synced?

Comment: Yes it is. My time is within one minute of the server's time.